# MediaError code 4 - I can't play audio on Safari

Tags: html, safari, web-audio-api

I'm having a problem with playing audio on Safari browser. The audio is playing perfectly on Chrome/Firefox/Edge. But when I play the audio on Safari, I'm always getting MediaError Code 4. Below is the code I'm using on React.

```
<audio 
    autoPlay
    onEnded={() => dispatch(stopPlaybackAction())}
    {...props}
>
  <source src={playbackObjectURL} type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Hoping you can help me make it work on Safari.

Comment: What is the file format?

Comment: Hi @ChetanSinghal , the audio source is always on blob.

`blob:http://localhost:3000/eba4ce8a-19d4-44bc-bfb6-9f4f82fd3d1f`

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The this solution: To specify the content type when constructing the blob:

```
var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Hi Chetan, thank you for this answer. I just want to ask, where does this arrayBuffer variable came from? Thank you!

Comment: This is just for reference, you can pass your blob data object in it. but anyways i have done more exploration on it and it is known issue of safari for audio and video file..